# How to go to a second tableview controller (from plist) based on specific first collectionview selection?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, plist

I have a CollectionViewController loading custom CollectionViewCells. The elements in the CollectionViewCell are populated by a plist file:

plist1:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Example Title</string>
        <key>Description</key>
        <string>Short description...</string>
        <key>Time</key>
        <string>Feb 6, 4:45</string>
        <key>Background</key>
        <string>Default</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Example Title 2</string>
        <key>Description</key>
        <string>Short description...</string>
        <key>Time</key>
        <string>Feb 6, 4:45</string>
        <key>Background</key>
        <string>Default2</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

When an item in the CollectionView is selected I need the view to go to a new TableViewController populated by a separate plist file. The TableViewController that is loaded should be dependent on what CollectionViewItem is selected, which is dependent on the plist entry. I would prefer a way to do this besides hardcoding what to do if IndexRow 1/2/etc is selected.

plist2:

```
<dict>
    <key>List1</key>
    <array>
        <string>Item1</string>
        <string>Item2</string>
        <string>Item3</string>
    </array>
    <key>List2</key>
    <array>
        <string>Item1</string>
        <string>Item2</string>
        <string>Item3</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

**Basically:**

**CollectionView -> CollectionViewCell1 (from plist1) -> TableView1 (from plist2)**

**CollectionView -> CollectionViewCell2 (from plist1) -> TableView2 (from plist2)**

Comment if more clarification or details are needed as I'm finding this difficult to describe in complete clarity.

Comment: what is the plist2 look like? two list of array?

Comment: I just added what plist2 currently is in the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done by adding another key in plist1 to specify the list that will be used in plist2 for TableViewController

```
<array>
<dict>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>Example Title</string>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>Short description...</string>
    <key>Time</key>
    <string>Feb 6, 4:45</string>
    <key>Background</key>
    <string>Default</string>
    <key>ListName</key>
    <string>List1</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>Example Title 2</string>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>Short description...</string>
    <key>Time</key>
    <string>Feb 6, 4:45</string>
    <key>Background</key>
    <string>Default2</string>
    <key>ListName</key>
    <string>List2</string>
</dict>
```

Add a variable in TableViewController

```
var listName = ""
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // get list from plist2

    // then reload table
}
```

and your prepareForSegue function

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let indexPathRow = sender as! Int
    let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! TableViewController
    destination.listName = // get your list name from plist1 based on index path row
}
```

at last when the cell is selected, then perform the segue

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // pass which indexpath row is selected
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showTableView", sender: indexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: For the most part the code you provided was extremely useful and I finally got it to work. Thank you!